# Reading List of WebElements in selenium

Tags: java, list, selenium

i'm novice with selenium and i've following site:
http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html

Using pagefactory I I want to get all actual prices of items in one list.

```
@FindBy (css=".price") List<WebElement> prices;
public ArrayList<String> getPrices(){
    ArrayList<String> pricesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement we:prices){
        pricesList.add(we.getText());                   
    }
        return pricesList;      
}
```

Code above can give me 4 prices, 2 normal + 1 old and 1 called 'special offer'
How can i change code to receive only 2 normal and 1 special offer price? I don't need old values of prices.

By the way code above is good for reading similar values from site using pagefactory?

When i get these 3 prices i want to compare all values with prices on item site, i think I know how to do it, but problem is in 4 instead of 3 values in my List of WebElements

Comment: FindAll or FindBys will be helpful for this case?

Comment: Is your question solved or you are still looking for an Answer?

Comment: I asked another question about List in comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this css selector

```
@FindBy(css=".price-box .regular-price,.special-price")
```

Updated with more rigid solutions

```
@FindBy (css=".price-box") List<WebElement> prices;
public ArrayList<String> getPrices(){
    ArrayList<String> pricesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement we : prices){
        // Check if there is an old-price 
        if (we.findElements(By.css('.old-price')).size() != 0) {
            // Assuming you will take special price if there's an old-price
            priceList.add(we.findElement(By.css('.special-price')).getText());
        } else {
            pricesList.add(we.getText());
        }
    }
    return pricesList;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thats works for me, before this post i 've tried FindAll with 2x FindBy, but with this approach i have problems with order of prices. Way to get prices is good for page factory, or maybe there's better way?