# Returning all of elements in List or only one element

Tags: java, list, selenium

I've the following test, it compares prices on this site http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html after clicking on product image (on item page).
First code has a method which gives access to whole List on Test, and in test I called for string elements saved in second List, it works for me, but i thinking about a method which returns only one string element instead of the whole list.
Which way is better to test?

Also second script doesn't work properly yet, on second iteration it gives me java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException, also I don't know why, maybe you can help me?
My first question is which way is better to return elements?
On the next test cases, i have do to a test which needs only one element, in this case approach number 2 will be better, and I can use it in comparing prices.

```
  public void test2(){          //zgodność cen w Mobile i stronach przedmiotów
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
  Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
  driver.get(baseUrl);  
  HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
  objHomePage.clickMobile();                    //przejście do mobile
  Mobile objMobile = new Mobile(driver);
  logger.debug(objMobile.getPrices());
  ArrayList<String> prices = new ArrayList<>();
  prices = objMobile.getPrices();               //pobieranie cen do lisy
  List<WebElement> itemLinks = objMobile.getLinks();
  int size = itemLinks.size();                  //rozmiar tablicy
  logger.debug(size);
  Item objItem = new Item(driver);
  String price1, price2;
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++){                    //pętla po produktach
      price1=prices.get(i);                     //pobieranie ceny z Mobile
      itemLinks.get(i).click();
      price2=objItem.getPrices();               //pobieranie ceny z Item
      logger.debug(i);
      logger.debug(price1);
      logger.debug(price2);
      Assert.assertTrue(price1.equals(price2)); //asercja
      driver.navigate().back();                 //powrót do mobile
      }
```

}

and page object method for this test:

```
public ArrayList<String> getPrices(){
    ArrayList<String> pricesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement we:prices){
        pricesList.add(we.getText());                   //pobieranie cen
    }
        return pricesList;      
}
```

Second approach, the method has one argument, and returns only one element

```
  public void test2(){          //zgodność cen w Mobile i stronach przedmiotów
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
  Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
  driver.get(baseUrl);  
  HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
  objHomePage.clickMobile();                    //przejście do mobile
  Mobile objMobile = new Mobile(driver);
  logger.debug(objMobile.getPrices(1));
  ArrayList<String> prices = new ArrayList<>();
  //prices = objMobile.getPrices();             //pobieranie cen do lisy
  List<WebElement> itemLinks = objMobile.getLinks();
  int size = itemLinks.size();                  //rozmiar tablicy
  logger.debug(size);
  Item objItem = new Item(driver);
  String price1, price2;
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++){                    //pętla po produktach
      //price1=prices.get(i);                       //pobieranie ceny z Mobile
      itemLinks.get(i).click();
      price2=objItem.getPrices();               //pobieranie ceny z Item
      logger.debug(i);
      logger.debug(objMobile.getPrices(i));
      logger.debug(price2);
      Assert.assertTrue(objMobile.getPrices(i).equals(price2)); //asercja
      driver.navigate().back();                 //powrót do mobile
      }
```

Page object model method for second way:

```
public String getPrices(int index){

    String cena = (prices.get(index)).getText();
        return cena;                    //pobieranie cen    
}
```

Comment: If the comments can help us understand your question, can you make them english please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading List of WebElements in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189834/reading-list-of-webelements-in-selenium)